# App is crashing if using Core Data (attribute of type boolean)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data, attributes

I addded a new attribute (of type boolean) into my core data model and my data.swift class. I try to run my app after I added the attribute. All works fine. Now I try to work with the new attribute. I wrote some code, which work is working with the attribute. Now I tried a 2nd time to run the app. It's crashing. Does someone knows why?

Comment: Please show us your Core Data Model

Comment: I posted a link with the image of the data model into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A `Bool` is not an object, so it can't be managed. Instead, set the property to an `NSNumber`.

`NSNumber` has a property called `boolValue` that you can get and set to use it as a boolean.

Comment: But how can I use this NSNumber? Does it give back a 0 or a 1?

Comment: When you want to get the boolean value you would type, in your case, hatDatum.boolValue and when you want to set it you'd call hatDatum = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES (or NO)] ;

Comment: Ok. So if I want to check if the boolean is true I have to write: `if hatDatum.boolValue = YES {} `?

Comment: My bad, you're using Swift. To check the value, you should be able to just type if(hatDatum == true).

Comment: Ok. And if I want to set a bool value: `hatDatum = true / false`?

Comment: Hmm, since aufgabe is a string, have you tried just setting the text to it? cell.textLabel!.text = daten[indexPath.row].aufgabe

Comment: I want to write the text/entry from `aufgabe` into the `textLabel` from a cell. It was working before I used the new attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your new DataModel isn't the same as you used when you created the datastore.

So you have to delete your app from your simulator. Then start your app again an it should work.